# Electricity and Magnetism: Relevant?

Tags: mathematics, physics

The computer science major at my university requires that I take a sequence in either biology, chemistry, and physics, plus an additional natural science course (which I might fill with meteorology).  Since I'm into game development, physics is the obvious choice.  That, and I go to a big pre-med school; why damage my GPA being weeded out from a path I never wanted to take?

There are two main versions of the physics sequence, both covering the same material; one in three semesters, one in two, which I'm interested in.  The course descriptions (the best info I can get right now) follow;

> **PHY 131: Classical Physics I**
>
> First part of a two-semester physics sequence for physical-sciences or
>   engineering majors who have a strong mathematics background and are
>   ready for a fast learning pace. It covers mechanics, wave motion,
>   kinetic theory, and thermodynamics. Calculus is used concurrently with
>   its development in MAT 131. Three lecture hours and one recitation
>   hour per week. The Laboratory component, PHY 133 (Lab 1), could be
>   taken concurrently.

Since that's motion, waves, etc. it's obviously extremely useful, and therefore worthy of my attention.  No question there.  I'm going to take this in Spring of '13.

> **PHY 132: Classical Physics II**
>
> Second part of a two-semester physics sequence for physical-sciences
>   or engineering majors who have a strong mathematics background and are
>   ready for a fast learning pace. It covers electromagnetism, electric
>   circuit theory, and optics. Calculus is used concurrently with its
>   development in MAT 132. Three lecture hours and one recitation hour
>   per week. The Laboratory component, PHY 134, may be taken
>   concurrently.

[(For reference, the descriptions for the three-semester versions are at this link, because they're a bit more descriptive.)](http://sb.cc.stonybrook.edu/bulletin/current/academicprograms/phy/courses.php/#125)

What I want to know is this; besides the obvious things like possible game design elements, does the material in PHY 132 play any significant role in game physics or similar?  If so, what are some examples?

I ask because if I can skimp on the material, I might take a PHY 132 equivalent online next summer at some community college.  That way I can ease the pressure on myself and free up a slot for something interesting.

At the very least, I might take a PHY 126 (part 2/3) equivalent online so I can take the more relaxed PHY 127 (part 3/3) that fall.  But I'd prefer the former option.

Any tips?

Comment: Well, I think this question is either too localized or not constructive. But I'll say that I took the full physics series (the harder one with calculus) and I think that's been pretty helpful. I say take as many as you can. Not so sure about taking it online, as physics is a complicated course and it's nice to have things explained to you.

Comment: They might be relevant if you were going to make a game that had those specific things as core features.  Otherwise neither of them probably are.  Most games fake that kind of stuff, ignore it entirely, or use an off-the-shelf physics engine of some kind (that either fakes it or ignores it).

Comment: Physics is the study of how our universe works. Whether "how something works" is important is kind of up to you. Optics = "study of how light works." Pretty important, for example, if you want to write a renderer/raytracer or if you just want to have a deeper appreciation of how renderers work (mostly by faking as much as possible), but it's not necessarily required to write a game.

Comment: Take the most interesting class. When I interview candidates, I'd rather see they know a lot about something they're really passionate about, than a little about everything they thought was going to be a useful job skill. The former indicates a curious and inquisitve mindset, which in the long run is more useful than knowing the inane details of particular hardware.

Comment: The thing is that Physics II is required for me, because I need a science sequence (and there's no way in hell I'm getting caught in the pre-med crossfire).  There are things I'm looking forward to sinking my teeth into, don't get me wrong.  It's just an issue of whether I need to have most of this particular class down pat or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're specifically interested in graphics/rendering, having some E&M and optics wouldn't be a bad thing.  You won't use it *directly*, but just having that background knowledge could be helpful for a rendering programmer to understand and contextualize rendering theory and algorithms.  After all, graphics is the simulation of light, which is an EM wave - even though we don't simulate it down to that level of detail.

More generally, I think that some physics background is helpful for programming / game development in general because of skills it teaches that are applicable beyond physics: dimensional analysis, making quick order-of-magnitude estimates of quantities, analyzing extreme cases (e.g. what happens when some quantity is very small or very large), guessing which effects in a complicated system are worth modeling and which are subtle enough to be ignored.  And of course it'll give you a lot of math practice, including vector math (E&M particularly uses vectors a lot), which you'll use all over the place in game development.

Comment: I'm not questioning Physics I.  At all.  I know DAMN well how useful that will be.  Like I said above, it's more than anything about how well I should have E&M down, about how much energy I should devote to it.  To analogize, I should be very familiar with Computer Science I; and I am, because I've been coding for a year.  If all I need is the gist of E&M, then I obviously don't need to stress out over it, right?

Comment: Optics governs how light bends and otherwise behaves when presented with things like mirrors and lenses. A detailed understanding is quite useful for graphics engine development and pops up in relatively surprising places such as coding Portal-style portals.